# Returning a single array value with each method call starting at index 0 and incrementing 1 with each call.

Tags: java, arrays

Hey guy I have searched the web and am having a hard time finding an answer to this question so Im thinking it may not be possible, am I able to use a method to call an single array variable with each call starting at index[0] and incrementing 1 each time I call the method to go throught the entire array? Or is there a better way to do it like maybe remove the first array variable each time?

Thanks for any help and keep in mind that I am a begginer and am just trying to learn the best way to do things.

Comment: If you want the value specific at an array location, then yes it's possible - it's the same as passing any other value.  I'd want to see an example of what you're referring to though, since it's not entirely clear from the question as it stands.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  The statement _"call an single array variable with each call"_ doesn't make sense. One doesn't "call" an array variable.  From your description you could want just a simple array-access loop, as described below by @hvgotcodes, but you could also be looking for a method that sequentially _returns_ elements of an array... i.e. an array iterator.  Which is it?

Comment: It usually helps to explain with an example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood you want something like an [Iterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html), and it's perfectly possible. Here's an example:

```
public class IteratorTest{

    static int[] numbers = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    static int index = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            System.out.println(getNext());
        }
    }

    public static int getNext(){
        return numbers[index++];
    }

}
```

calling `getNext()` wil throw an exception when `index >= numbers.length` but this is pretty much the idea from what I could understand.

---

**EDIT**

I have an ArrayIterator here, I thought the code above would be more didactic. But if an implementation of Iterator is interesting (as @David Conrad suggested), I have one right here:

```
public class ArrayIterator<E> implements Iterator<E>{

    private E[] elements;
    private int index;

    public ArrayIterator(E[] elements){
        this.elements = elements;
        index = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext(){
        return index < elements.length;
    }

    @Override
    public E next(){
        if(!hasNext()){
            throw new NoSuchElementException("No more elements in the array.");
        }
        return elements[index++];
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove operation is not supported.");
    }

}
```

Comment: You should `implement java.util.Iterator<Integer>` and implement the `hasNext()` method. Rename `getNext()` to `next()` and have it throw `java.util.NoSuchElementException` if hasNext() is false, and implment the `remove()` method and simply have it always throw `UnsupportedOperationException`. Get rid of `static` everywhere, and pass the array in to the constructor, and you'll have a nice IntArrayIterator. (Then make it generic.)

Comment: @DavidConrad, I added an example of a generic ArrayIterator

Comment: I was about to do +1, but then your answer started getting more and more complicated.

Comment: Just wanna say that out of all the above answers I'm pretty sure I've found a solution to my problem. I'm going to use if statements with the hasnext and next methods. Thanks guys for the quick responses!

Comment: @NotaNoobForever, perhaps you should accept this as the correct answer then :-)

Answer (score 1):

You question is a bit unclear, but I think this is the gist of what you want to do

```
for (int i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++) {
    someFunction(someArray[i]);
}
```

of course you need to make sure `someArray` and `someFunction` are defined.

Comment: This code will print out the entire array as it goes through the for loop. What I'm trying to do is print each next array variable starting at 0 with each method call.